# WAMP windows 10 slow response from localhost

Tags: wordpress, performance, localhost, wamp, windows-10

I was using "Wampserver (64 bits & PHP 5.5) 2.5" on Windows 7 and the response time from localhost was 2-3 seconds as I clicked on links and loaded pages.  This was fine.

I have now upgraded to windows 10.  Since then, now the response time to load pages is anywhere between 20 to 25 seconds for my wordpress site. It says "Waiting for response from localhost..." in the status bar.  I get the same slow response with Firefox, Explorer, and Edge browsers.

I have turned off the windows 10 IIS and WWW Services features also.

Any suggestions that might speed it up or help me determine what is slowing it down?

Comment: When connecting to MySQL try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. This worked for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to do this and I will give it a try?  Do I need to modify an INI file.  Thanks for helping out

Comment: You just type 127.0.0.1 in the browser address instead of localhost

Comment: Sure, open the `wp-config-sample.php` file which should be located at the root of your wordpress site. Inside there change `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');` to `define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');`

Comment: Sorry, not `wp-config-sample.php` just `wp-config.php`

Comment: Outstanding pmahomme!!! That made a huge difference and fixed it.  One more question.  When I am on www.wampserver.com/en site to download WAMP, should I switch to the version named "wampserver (64bits & php 5.6.15 & PHP 7) 3.....Is that just the latest version, not sure what the difference is.

Comment: You can download WAMPServer from the SourceForge links on the WAMPServer web site OR our other repository http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/ This other repo is sometimes more up to date as updating SourceForge sometimes takes longer, but only a day or so at most. The latest version of WAMPServer is V3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a long time asked question but here I just experienced it.

XDEBUG is a performance killing tool when improperly configured.

If you don't need it, you can simple comment it from your `php.ini` file (look at the line loading it with `zend_extension=php_xdebug.dll`.

If you need it, try to disable autostart :

```
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```